# Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: [Error: connection closed]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my nodejs program it is giving an error:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = Server = require('mongodb').Server;


var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/prisync_mamy';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

    var collection = db.collection('urlAnalysis_mamy');
var cursor = collection.find({channel_name:'urlAnalysis_mamy'});



cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Fetched:', doc);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

> Error: [Error: connection closed]

but when i type mongo on terminal it is running fine.

Comment: Those codes work well on me... any other errors?

Comment: no not any other error.

Comment: Do you have MongoDB server installed on your machine and is it running? You can typically test this by typing `mongo` in a terminal.

Comment: ya its working fine. now i am using another program that is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was file security on the new server and mongdb npm module files, so I had to use "chown" command to own all files and then run "npm install", after that MongoDB client worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

The exception from running your code is

```
TypeError: db.collection is not a function
```

and that tells you the *collection* keyword do not exist in the variable *db*. Look at the [mongodb npm page](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) and you should do this:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/prisync_mamy';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const db = client.db('prisync_mamy');

    ...
});
```